# Clear Autofilled Login Form in Chrome for React App

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, autofill

What is the best way to ensure that we can clear autofilled fields in Chrome within a React app?  I've got a login credentials update form that I want to prevent Chrome from auto-filling.  However, I also want to set the email address to the value which I've already retrieved from the database.

I've added the "autocomplete='off'" attribute to the form itself as well as to the email and password inputs.  This does not seem to actually prevent Chrome from auto-filling them--which I'm aware is a known "feature".

Here is my form as it sits in my render() method:

```
<form id="credentials"
          name="credentials"
          acceptCharset="UTF-8"
          onSubmit={this.saveAndContinue}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          autoComplete="off"
          noValidate="novalidate">
      <div className="container">
        <div className={this.props.isModal ? "wrapper content login-wrapper" : "wrapper content"}>
          <div className="dynamic-row">
            <div className="required italic warning-box">
              * For security purposes, once you update your login credentials here, you will be immediately logged out
                and redirected to the login form.
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"/>
            <div className="box margin-top-15">
              <fieldset>
                <ul>
                  <ul className="dynamic-row">
                    <li className="column-6">
                      <div className="form-field">
                        <label htmlFor="title" className="margin-top-0">Email</label>
                        <input id="email"
                               name="email"
                               type="email"
                               autoComplete="off"
                               value={this.state.credentials.email.value}
                               onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                               onBlur={this.handleInputTouched}
                               tabIndex="100"/>
                        <div className="margin-top-10">
                          {
                            !this.state.formValidator.email ?
                              <span className="required">*Invalid email address</span> : null
                          }
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="column-6">
                      <div className="form-field">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <ReactPasswordStrength
                          minLength={8}
                          minScore={2}
                          scoreWords={['weak', 'okay', 'good', 'strong', 'stronger']}
                          changeCallback={this.handlePasswordMeterChange}
                          inputProps={{name: "password", tabIndex: "102", autoComplete: "off", value: ""}}
                        />
                        <div className="margin-top-10">
                          {
                            !this.state.formValidator.password ?
                              <span className="required">*Password is too short</span> : null
                          }
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </ul>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <fieldset className="wizard-buttons-bottom">
        <div className="form-field right margin-top-15">
          <button type="submit"
                  className="bttn blue submit-bttn"
                  tabIndex="102"
                  disabled={!this.state.formValidator.allValid}>
            Update
          </button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

By looking at the code you can see I'm using the awesome 'react-password-strength' component found at https://github.com/mmw/react-password-strength.  So, there is an additional level of complexity in that I also need to clear this field and not allow it to be auto-filled by Chrome AT ALL.

In summary Chrome is auto-filling both the email and password fields and overwriting what I retrieve from the database for the email field.